# ListMultimap vs. Multimap in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Anyone can give example and explain what's the difference between the two? I've read the documentation and it seems that both have same methods and properties.

Comment: @pskink ok but what can listmultimap do that multimap can't viceversa? If it says in multimap that it maps key to multiple values that I think it's similar. Could you give a simple example to show how they're different in usage?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're talking about [`Multimap`](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.collection/Multimap-class.html) and [`ListMultimap`](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.collection/ListMultimap-class.html) from [`package:quiver`](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver) (which is exported by the Flutter SDK), `Multimap` is an *abstract* class that cannot be directly instantiated.  It provides *factory* constructors that instantiate a `ListMultimap`.

This is similar to how `Map` is an abstract class that provides factory constructors that instantiate a `LinkedHashMap`.

**TL;DR**: `Multimap`'s default implementation is a `ListMultimap`, so they are the same thing.

Comment: Why make another one if it’s the same thing? I was hoping that ListMultiMap would be like a normal list with multimap as values wherein you can get them by element, but it seems different from what I thought.

Comment: They're separate for the same reason people use abstract base classes at all: to define an interface without requiring specific implementation details.  Making `ListMultimap` a separate class from `Multimap` allows `ListMultimap` to provide `List`-specific methods without affecting the `Multimap` interface.  For example, `ListMultimap.operator []` returns a `List`, whereas `SetMultimap.operator []` returns a `Set`.  Meanwhile `Multimap.operator []` promises only to return an `Iterable`.